# How to create matrix of points by X, Y coordinate in Python?

Tags: python, point, mesh

I have: 
X min, Y min and X max, Y max.
Need to create mesh of point with distance 2000.0 m between point in this boundaries.

My code:

```
while minY < maxY:
    minY += 2000.0
        while minX < maxX:
            minX += 2000.0
            X.append(minX)
            Y.append(minY)
     X.append(minX)
     Y.append(minY)
```

gave me: 1 row by X (from min to max) and 1 colon of point by Y () from
Xmax - last X.

Please, help me to create rows of points/ mesh grid.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  What do you expect for a result in this?  Please show in Python terms.  If you print this matrix mesh, how does the output appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this code does what you need. However, you might want to go through some basic python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to help you get started.

```
import numpy as np
# define the lower and upper limits for x and y
minX, maxX, minY, maxY = 0., 20000., 10000., 50000.
# create one-dimensional arrays for x and y
x = np.linspace(minX, maxX, (maxX-minX)/2000.+1)
y = np.linspace(minY, maxY, (maxY-minY)/2000.+1)
# create the mesh based on these arrays
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

If you need the mesh to be in 1-dimensional arrays, you can reshape them:

```
X = X.reshape((np.prod(X.shape),))
Y = Y.reshape((np.prod(Y.shape),))
```

You can then easily zip them into

```
coords = zip(X, Y)
```

Comment: Ok, but it hard to create   pair of X, Y coordinate  to create points after this. (coords = zip(X, Y)).

Comment: Is it possible to use just a nested loop for this?